# libvirt log under /var/log/libvirt/qemu Display time is UTC how How can I let it show the local time?

Tags: kvm, libvirt

libvirt log under /var/log/libvirt/qemu  Display time is UTC how  How can I let it show the local time?

Like below log:

`qemu: terminating on signal 15 from pid 118813
2016-01-31 09:07:08.465+0000: shutting down
2016-01-31 09:09:14.958+0000: starting up libvirt version: 1.2.21, qemu version: 1.1.2
LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none /usr/bin/kvm -name test10.0.10.35 -S -machine pc-1.1,accel=kvm -cpu host -m 16384 -smp 2,sockets=2,cores=1,threads=1 -uuid f498447b-ebad-ce98-e5fa-0cdfecad7371 -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-test10.0.10.35/monitor.sock,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=2016-01-31T17:09:14 -no-shutdown -boot order=cd,menu=on -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x1.0x2 -drive file=/home/vmstorage/images/test.img,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=qcow2,bps=85445632,iops_rd=1000,iops_wr=1000 -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0 -drive if=none,id=drive-ide0-1-1,readonly=on,format=raw -device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,unit=1,drive=drive-ide0-1-1,id=ide0-1-1 -netdev tap,fd=24,id=hostnet0 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:cc:8b:45,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -device usb-tablet,id=input0 -vnc 0.0.0.0:3 -vga cirrus -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5
Domain id=34 is tainted: high-privileges
Domain id=34 is tainted: host-cpu
char device redirected to /dev/pts/5`

2016-01-31 09:09:14.958+0000 this time display is utc How can I let it show the local time?

Answer (score 0):

Libvirt will always use UTC for all logging and never localtime. This primarily stems from a need to have the logging functions be thread safe without requiring any locking, and there was not a thread safe API for converting to localtime. Hence libvirt decided to simply fix on using UTC for everything, giving added benefit of consistency both across hosts and in the face of timezone changes.